# How to save fragment onButtonClick and load on next program start

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-savedstate

I have an app where I have a fragment.Let's call it mainScreen. In mainScreen there's a `button` and `onClick()` opens second fragment. Let's call it FragmentHomePage. In FragmentHomePage i have a `retrofit`. There's a button named logOut. My problem is, when user not clicked logOut, i want to save this fragment and load this fragment. In default when app starts, opens mainScreen, but if user not clicks logOut, i need open FragmentHomePage on app start. How can i do this?

```
public class FragmentHomePage extends BaseFragment {

View mainView;
TextView fullName, userName, email;
Button logOut;
ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient.getInstance();
SupportObjToken supportopToken = new SupportObjToken();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_page, container, false);

    init(mainView);
    newTokenCall();

    return mainView;
}

private void init(View v) {
    fullName = v.findViewById(R.id.fullName);
    userName = v.findViewById(R.id.user);
    email = v.findViewById(R.id.mail);
    logOut = v.findViewById(R.id.logOut);
}

public void newTokenCall() {

    String clientID = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getClientID();
    String clientSecret = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getClientSecret();
    String refreshToken = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getRefreshToken();
    String newRefreshToken = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getNewRefreshToken();
    final String firstName = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getFirstName();
    final String lastName = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getLastName();
    final String mail = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getEmail();
    final String user = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUsername();

    supportopToken.setGrantType("refresh_token");
    supportopToken.setClientId(clientID);
    supportopToken.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    supportopToken.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

    Call<ResponseBody> newToken = apiClient.newToken(supportopToken);
    newToken.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    String newDataAccess = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(newDataAccess);

                    String newAccessToken = obj.getString("accessToken");
                    String newRefreshToken = obj.getString("refreshToken");

                    SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setNewAccessToken(newAccessToken);
                    SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setNewRefreshToken(newRefreshToken);

                    fullName.setText(firstName + " " + lastName);
                    userName.setText(user);
                    email.setText(mail);

                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (response.code() == 401) {
                supportopToken.setRefreshToken(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getNewRefreshToken());

                Call<ResponseBody> newToken1 = apiClient.newToken(supportopToken);
                newToken1.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            try {
                                String newDataAccess = response.body().string();
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(newDataAccess);

                                String newAccessToken = obj.getString("accessToken");
                                String newRefreshToken = obj.getString("refreshToken");

                                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setNewAccessToken(newAccessToken);
                                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setNewRefreshToken(newRefreshToken);

                                fullName.setText(firstName + " " + lastName);
                                userName.setText(user);
                                email.setText(mail);

                            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You're on failure getting new Token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You're on failure getting new Token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

How can i do this part? Thanks. Yeah and not give negative vote. I'm a beginner on this site)).

Here's the activity where i'm launching the fragments.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentChangeListener {
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ApiClient.initializeInstance("simple web page");

    fragmentActivity = new FragmentActivity();

    this.replaceFragment(fragmentActivity, true);

    SharedPreferencesManager.init(this);
}

@Override
public void replaceFragment(BaseFragment fragment, Boolean isAddToBackStack) {
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.toString());
    transaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
    transaction.commit();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mainScreen button `onclick`, add a key to shared preferences like this

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("state", "logged_in");
 editor.apply();
```

inside your logOut button onclick in `FragmentHomePage` add the following code

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("state", "logged_out");
 editor.apply();
```

Now inside your first fragment's oncreate add this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE); 
  String state = prefs.getString("state", "state");
  if(state.equals("logged_in"){
   //load second fragment here
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

save a boolean value in SharedPreferences with default value false.

```
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext()).edit().putBoolean("ISUSERALREADYLOGGEDIN", false).apply();
```

when ever you come to the  FragmentHomePage , set this value to true.

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext()).edit().putBoolean("ISUSERALREADYLOGGEDIN", true).apply();
```

When user clicks logout button , set this value to false again.

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext()).edit().putBoolean("ISUSERALREADYLOGGEDIN", false).apply();
```

From the Base Activity which is keeping these fragments,
When you launch the mainScreen fragment, check this value, with this code :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext()).getBoolean("ISUSERALREADYLOGGEDIN", false);
```

If the value is true, launch the HomeFragment, else launch the mainScreen fragment.

Use this function to launch the fragment:

```
public void launchFragmentByReplacing(Fragment fragment, String incomingFragmentTag) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(frameLayout.getId(), fragment, incomingFragmentTag);
    transaction.commit();
    manager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

In your case, right before :

```
this.replaceFragment(fragmentActivity, true);
```

check for the SharedPref value.

```
Boolean isloggedIn = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext()).getBoolean("ISUSERALREADYLOGGEDIN", false);
    if(isloggedIn) //is true
    this.replaceFragment(new FragmentActivity(), true);
    else
    this.replaceFragment(new FragmentHomePage(), true);
```

Comment: Yeah man, i tried this method too, but beside SharedPreferences i tried Bundle

Comment: try with sharedPref. And can you share the activity code where you are launching the fragment ?

Comment: Yes wait a minute.

Comment: But where's the sharedPrefBoolean? Where to initialize it?

Comment: its automated. it will take the default Shared Preferences automatically and assign it a default value false, if it is not created yet. 
The line PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext()).getBoolean("ISUSERALREADYLOGGEDIN", false); will do that part.

now when you go to FragmentHomePage, in the onCreateView write this line : 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext()).edit().putBoolean("ISUSERALREADYLOGGEDIN", true).apply();

That's all the initialization you will need.

Comment: check my ans again. this might clear your confusion.

Comment: The AppLevelConstraints.getAppContext() is nothing but Context.